# How to deploye GTK# application on MAC OS X machine

Tags: macos, xamarin, gtk#, xamarin-studio

I am developing GTK# application using XAMARIN Studio.

Can anyone tell me how to create package (installation package) for MAC OS X.

I am new for MAC OS X but i found that there is .DMG file for MAC.

how can i convert .exe to .dmg file.

GTK# is generating .exe file but i want .dmg to run in mac machine to install application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin Studio will run that EXE with the Mono runtime. You would either have to create .app with [macpack](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/macpack.1.html) or maybe follow [these instructions.](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app)